# How can I install Ubuntu inside Windows?

Tags: system-installation, windows

I have **sony vaio** laptop running on **windows 10**.

Can I install ubuntu 15.10 **inside** windows?

Comment: **Inside** Windows? Pff, you wouldn't want to do that. Do you mean alongside windows?

Comment: Unless you install it as a Virtual Machine, you can't install one Operating System inside another... So do you want to install it as a VM **inside** Windows, or **alongside** Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There *used to be* a system called `wubi` that allowed just that. However it caused a ton of problems due to the instability of Windows, so it's deprecated...

If you want a stable solution, you *could*:

- install Windows inside a virtual machine on Ubuntu (tons of free and open solutions out there)
- install both inside a hypervisor...